# How can I configure Rails 3 to output colored logging to the terminal, but non-colored to log files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, logging

There's a rails configuration option of `config.colorize_logging` that you can set to turn it on/off across the board.  It's not clear to me where to configure (or write a logger subclass) that can keep colorized logging to my terminal without inserting all the goofy control characters into log files

`Rails.logger` is a `ActiveSupport::BufferedLogger`:

```
#<ActiveSupport::BufferedLogger:0x0000010524ae18 @level=0, @buffer={}, 
   @auto_flushing=1, @guard=#<Mutex:0x0000010524ab70>,
   @log=#<File:/Users/ian/coding/some_poject/log/development.log>>
```

Though it also seems to be splitting the output to `$stdout` at some point, and it's not clear to me where hooks are to configure the loggers.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this to your configuration:

```
console do
    config.colorize_logging = true
    Rails.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
end
```

The `console do` should only execute if you're, well, using a console.

The `Rails.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)` is something I add to make the logging use STDOUT automatically.

Hope this helps.